# Registering with Facebook Account

Tags: asp.net

I have a website with custom login and registration page. Everything working fine. Now I would like to get the member's data from Facebook, like first name, last name, email, dob, gender, picture and place to simplfy registration process..

I created app account in Facebook and got appID and canvas url also.

I am looking for a FB connect button, when user clicks on the button, it should authenticate FB account and retrive data from Facebook.

Give me some sample code.

Comment: `Give me some sample code`. SO is not a place where your requirements get translated to code. What have you researched/tried?

Comment: @verisimilitude The very fact he thinks all he needs is a copy-pasteable "connect button" should answer that question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Gigya plugin](http://developers.gigya.com/040_Demos/005_Social_Login), they have sample code on their website.